# SQL Select query in kotlin exposed DSL

Tags: kotlin, dsl

What is the translation of the following SQL query in [Kotlin Exposed DSL](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL)?

```
SELECT id FROM `Sessions` WHERE session_id="155924f2-31ff-4c2c-a8fa-7fb0afba0ff8""
```

I'm assuming that each session_id is unique in the table Sessions.
Right now I'm using the following code. I have a feeling that `.forEach` is superfluous. I can't find the right syntax to get rid of it.

```
            var sessionId = "155924f2-31ff-4c2c-a8fa-7fb0afba0ff8"
            var sessionIdInDb = 0
            Sessions.select { Sessions.session_id eq sessionId }.forEach {
                sessionIdInDb = it[Sessions.id].value
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exposed implements common collection methods such as `first()` allowing you to write something like:

```kotlin
val sessionIdInDb = Sessions
    .select { Sessions.session_id eq "155924f2-31ff-4c2c-a8fa-7fb0afba0ff8" }
    .first()[id]
    .value
```

Comment: Thank you! Here is my full code: https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/ktor_exposed_select_query .